# Where can I find the latest status of WebGL support in browsers?

Tags: cross-browser, webgl

Where can I find a regularly updated table that shows which browsers support WebGL and when they will support them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah, I found a site already: http://caniuse.com/#search=webgl

It shows many other types of HTML/CSS features and compatibility for each browser.

[image: 2011]

Keeping the old table for prosperity, here is the current one, as of Oct 2014:

[image: 2014]

Comment: Looks like all major browsers have at least partial support now (3 and a half years after you posted this). And if you break down by user, 45% of people use browsers with full support while a further 25% of people use browsers with partial support. I'm just starting on a project now which I don't expect to release until next year, so it looks like using WebGL is a pretty safe bet that most of my target audience will be able to use it when I release.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare I've updated the answer with some a more recent screenshot of the table.